# Gauge Metric Initialisation

Tags: metrics, prometheus

The [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_clientlibs/) states that “Gauges MUST start at 0”. Why would one require such assumption? The zeros could even disrupt averages or trigger boundary alerts.

I'm asking for insights and best-practices for realisation of a new opensource library.

Comment: I can't speak for the creators of Prometheus, but 0 sounds like a reasonable default for anything. (Meaning it's more reasonable for a gauge to start at 0 than any other value, possibly excluding NaN.)

And right next to that it says "you MAY offer a way for a given gauge to start at a different number". So it MUST start at zero only if an explicit initial value is not provided.

Comment: NaN should only be used where it mathematically makes sense, not as a "missing" value. It'd break _over_time and other math to use NaN in such a way.

Comment: What is mathematical sense of NaN @brian-brazil? The application for NaN is a placeholder for no value (such as devision by zero), and, why not an unset gauge. Whether zero is more applicable than any other number is highly dependent on the unit in use I'd think.

Comment: If you divide by 0 you get NaN, which is not the same as a missing sample.